# Vertical alignment and stretch behavior of 3 divs (1 with known fixed height + 2 with unknown height)

Tags: html, css

The title of this question was a difficult one to word given the specifics of the problem, so apologies if it doesn't highlight exactly what I'm asking.

Before I describe the problem, please note that I'm only looking for an ***IE10-compatible*** solution in ***pure html/css***.

[image]

As seen above, we have 3 divs (`#top`, `#mid`, `#bottom`). We know the height of the bottom div, but not top/mid.

Given this, is there a solution that would ensure that `#top` always shows its inner content and `#mid` always fills the gap between `#top` and `#bottom`?

**Note:** We can assume that at all times `(#top.height + #bottom.height) > #wrapper.height` where `#wrapper` is the container element around the 3 divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
#content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#footer {
  background: #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">#top Header - Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </div>
  <div id="content">#mid Content - Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </div>
  <div id="footer">#bottom Footer - fixed height: 20px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nearly! I'm looking to produce a scrollbar for the `.content` div only. Testing this out seems to cause the entire page to scroll. (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie0LX.png )

Comment: And yes, `.header` should be fixed by virtue of the fact that `.content` scrolls. Using `position:fixed` for `.header` only obscures `.content`'s content (as we can't apply a margin against an unknown height)

Comment: updated the answer to adjust the content height and avoid the header scroll with javascript.

Comment: Note in question: *"...in pure html/css"*. JS is off the table

Comment: sorry, I don't see a way to solve your problem in pure html/css

Comment: found a solution using `display: flex`, I've updated the answer